# ipod Touch Account Reset with a new user and Ipad 4 account currently used

Tags: ipod

I had my iPod Touch and created an apple id account. When i bought iPad4 i sold the iPod Touch but i used same apple id that was registered in my iPod. Will there be no conflict at all with regards to application, photos and updates since I am now using an Ipad? Now the iPod was reset and used by another user name. does the new owner of Ipod can still access my info? please help, i am worrying of the security and privacy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you signed out of your Apple ID with:

- iCloud
- iMessage
- Facetime
- iTunes and App Stores

### Or:

wiped the device before you sold it, you have nothing to worry about. The new owner of your old iPod, won't be able to access any of your data.

---

If you did **not** wipe the device, nor sign out of your Apple ID, then the best you can do is [change your Apple ID password](http://appleid.apple.com). This will, in effect, sign the new owner out of your Apple ID.

Even with an Apple ID change the new owner will be able to access:

- Any non-iCloud email accounts that you haven't since changed the password for.
- Any app's data that has already been installed.

So, change your Apple ID password, and other email passwords (i.e. Gmail), and that will prevent him from accessing your data any further. In addition he won't be able to download updates for apps left on the device.

Comment: I didn't even want to include this in the answer, but, for completion, if you have Find my i[Pod] enabled, and can still see the device, you could consider wiping it. I **strongly** recommend against doing this, however, as you could (and would) destroy information they have rightfully created on **their** device. At least try to contact them to see what they are willing to help you with.